# SSRS Report Server - Email on failure?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

My company uses SSRS to deliver reports to users, either by email subscriptions or by the user opening the Report Server page in their browser and clicking on the report they want, which then runs it against the db. I call this "Interactive mode".

My users are supposed to tell me when a report fails, so I can go fix it, but most of the time they don't.

So I need to go looking for failed reports. I can already see which email subscription reports have failed using the subscriptions report in SSRS, but I need a way to either generate an email or log a row to a table whenever one of the interactive mode reports fails.

I can't see anything obvious in Visual Studio that would allow me to do this, has anyone come up with a solution for this before?

Comment: Why would a report fail in the first place? If it's an error in the T-SQL you need to handle it there; not in the report.

Comment: The reports can fail for any number of reasons, missing tables, malformed data, out of date SQL code. You're exactly right, I need to go fix the T-SQL, but in order to do that I need to understand which reports are failing. We have thousands of reports and only a couple dozen fail.

Comment: You could check the error logs for SSRS, but those are files, they aren't stored in the data engine. If you're querying tables that don't exist the problem doesn't sound like it's SSRS at all, but the definition of the SQL being run.

Comment: I never said the problem was SSRS, I said the problem is I can't figure out what reports have failed in SSRS in interactive mode. You're saying there's log files stored outside of the database? What are they please? Where do I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there's a very helpful table in the ReportServer database named "ExecutionLog" which has exactly these details.

Answer (score 0):

By default SSRS maintains the subscriptions and errors info within Report server database.

- `Subscriptions` is catalog info table of all subscriptions in Report Server
- `SubscriptionHistory` maintains the extended details of the error.

Using following script, you can monitor the last status of all subscriptions at one place, rather than going through SSRS web interface. also, you could develop your own script based on this:

```
select  c.ItemID as ReportItemID,
        c.Name as ReportName,
        c.Path as ReportLocation,
        s.Description as SubscriptionTitle,
        EventType,
        LastRunTime,
        LastStatus,
        CreationDate
from Subscriptions as s
     join Catalog as c on s.Report_OID = c.ItemID 
Where   LastStatus like '%failed%'
      or LastStatus like '%Error%'  
      and (NOT LastStatus like '%0 Errors.')
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already know how to view details of subscriptions. What I want to know about are reports that are triggered ad-hoc via the Report Server webpage. Users are able to navigate to a report and click it to run it on demand. This activity doesn't seem to appear in the "Subscriptions" table.